# Why is my original hashset changed when I change a copy of it and how can I avoid it?

Tags: c#, hashset

The intent of the below code is that it updates what's in my database to match what the user selected in my frontend. The proper Guids are in the Session variable, and `_alreadyLinkedContacts` contains the users that are already in the database.

```
    protected void btnAssignContacts_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAssignContacts.Enabled = false;
        //Venn diagram:

        //(Only in session --> add(both in session and Database -> keep) Only in database --> remove )

        HashSet<Guid> contactsInSession = (HashSet<Guid>)Session[SelectedContactsSessionVar];
        HashSet<Guid> contactsInDatabase = _alreadyLinkedContacts;
        //Everything that's in the session should go in the database;
        HashSet<Guid> contactsToAdd = contactsInSession;
        //Base the set to remove on that in the database.
        HashSet<Guid> contactsToRemove = contactsInDatabase;

        // We don't need to add those that are in the database already;
        contactsToAdd.RemoveWhere(contactsInDatabase.Contains);
        MarketingDirector.AddContactsToMarketingList(contactsToAdd.ToList(), _marketinglist.Id);

        // Those that are currently in the session don't need to be removed from the database, all the others do.
        contactsToRemove.RemoveWhere(contactsInSession.Contains);
        MarketingDirector.RemoveContactsFromMarketingList(contactsToRemove.ToList(), _marketinglist.Id);
        btnAssignContacts.Text = "Contacts assigned";
    }
```

After `contactsToAdd` has been filtered, `contactsInSession` has been changed as well, excluding the same guids as are in my system. Because of this, it doesn't remove anything from `contactsToRemove` and anything that already was in my database is removed, instead of just the stuff that is not in the session.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Try HashSet<Guid> contactsInSession = new HashSet<Guid>((HashSet<Guid>)Session[SelectedContactsSessionVar]);

Comment: @artm Somehow, I doubt that will fix my problem, because I don't think the Session gets updated automatically. My problem is that my HashSet isn't copied by value, but by reference.

Comment: Weird. Are the two sets equal (reference equal)? i.e. does contactsToAdd == contactsToRemove return true? if so, you need to create a copy (contactsInDatabase = new HashSet<Guid>(_alreadyLinkedContacts) and the same for the other one and then run your code. If not, I have no idea why filtering one would filter the other.

Comment: @kha contactsToAdd and contactToRemove are never the same. The problem is that the HashSet I base my Hashset of contacts to add on gets changed when I change that second hashset. I want to remove the contacts that are shared by both HashSets from them so I only have those that I need to add or remove from the database.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. if the two sets are never the same, filtering one shouldn't have an effect on the other one. The side effect comes from one of these two lines:     contactsToAdd.RemoveWhere(contactsInDatabase.Contains); (OR)
            MarketingDirector.AddContactsToMarketingList(contactsToAdd.ToList(), _marketinglist.Id);. What happens if you move the .ToList() to where the first RemoveWhere() is and force the evaluation on that line instead? Would the second set change immediately or does it change after your call into the MarketingDirector.xxx?

Comment: ContactsInSession and contactsToAdd are the same when contactsToAdd is generated. ContactsInDatabase is the same as ContactsToRemove when ToRemove is created. There is always some overlap between contactsToAdd and contactsToRemove, and it's this overlap I want to remove. However, when I remove the overlap from contactsToAdd, the hashset ContactsInSession from which i constructed it also is changed, removing those that it shares with contactsInDatabase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to say in your comments when you do the following:

```
HashSet<Guid> contactsToAdd = contactsInSession;
```

You are assigning a second variable to reference the same `HashSet` as the original. If you do the folowing you will create a new `HashSet` that is a copy of the original.

```
HashSet<Guid> contactsToAdd = new HashSet<Guid>(contactsInSession);
```

You might want to do the same for all your assignments where you want a copy of the HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

You are making contactsToRemove and contactsInSession point to the same HashSet. Why wouldn't you expect contactsToRemove.RemoveWhere() to affect the contactsInSession HashSet ? I think you are missing a step which copies the data from one hashset to another, in your code you are always copying the reference not the content of the hashset.

Almost certainly these two lines

```
    //Everything that's in the session should go in the database;
    HashSet<Guid> contactsToAdd = contactsInSession;
    //Base the set to remove on that in the database.
    HashSet<Guid> contactsToRemove = contactsInDatabase;
```

Are incorrect ; they should copy the data from the source hashset not copy the reference pointer to that hashset. By doing reference copying you are simply declaring two variables which point to the same hashset - any changes made via either contactsToAdd OR contactsInSession will affect the same hashset.

Comment: Ah, so hashsets are copied byref? I thought that, like with strings or integers, it was a value copy. Is there a list somewhere of what gets copied as reference and what as a value?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs, everything is copied by value, but for reference types (i.e. classes rather than structs) the value is a reference.

Comment: The difference between Value and Reference types is really important in C# and .net. In general almost everything you will encounter in the .net world that is not a "simple type" (int, datetime, etc) will be a Reference Type (This is a gross exaggeration but it illustrates the point) and therefore you actually have to put considerable effort into copying the data from a Reference Type to another Reference Type. Helpfully HashSet like most collections have already done the heavy lifting in their constructor, so HashSet a = new HashSet(b) copies the contents of Hashset b into Hashset a.